# Deployment of silverlight 4 business application with WCF RIA

Tags: web-applications, iis-7, silverlight-4.0, iis-6, wcf-ria-services

After trying for long time I am not able to run my silverlight 4 business application successfully on my deployment server, where I don't have visual studio 2010 installed.

I have IIS 7.5, OS:windows web server 2008 R2, I installed RIA services, Silverlight 4 etc. I configured IIS it works for normal silverlight websites But this silverlight business application just stucks at loading animation of 100%. Hence, I am not even in my main page and didn't got any error.

I have read:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2009/11/23/understanding-the-wcf-in-wcf-ria-services.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh/archive/2010/03/16/ria-services-application-deployment.aspx

and seem working correct as they describe.

It would be really nice if someone could help to fine the error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Web platfrom Installer really solves the problem very easily. Just need to download and install it, which will help you to select, download, install and configure the features that we want to deploy, cool.